# Two ordered rings are isomorphic iff their positive semirings are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

I am looking for (a reference to) a proof that

> Two ordered rings are isomorphic  iff their positive ordered semirings are isomorphic.

The *positive semiring* of an ordered ring $R$ is here the set $A$ of all nonnegative elements of $R$ together with the operations, induced on $A$ by the operations from $R$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would imagine you just show how to reconstruct the original ring from its positive semiring.

Comment: Am I perhaps missing a subtlety? Both implications seem trivially true : an isomorphism of rings $\phi:R\to R'$ will induce an isomorphism of the positive semirings $P,P'$ by restriction, and an isomorphism of the positive semirings will extend uniquely to an isomorphism of rings since $R=-P\sqcup\lbrace 0\rbrace\sqcup P$ and $R'=-P'\sqcup\lbrace 0\rbrace\sqcup P'$...

Comment: Yes, it is an obvious theorem, but a reference to a textbook would be useful.